# Checking existence of combination in a list against a list of lists

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

If i have a list of list of integers `S:  [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]]`, and a single list `T: [2,3,1]`. I want to return true if T as a combination is contained in S. Assuming each element of `S` has same length as that of `T`.

In this case, I want to return true.

Restrictions: No sorting of any kind, and note S has all unique lists, but within a list, it can have duplicate elements.

How can I do this as efficiently as possible. I can iterate through each element of `S` and turn it into a set and compare it with `set(T)`, but that seems very slow if size of `S` and length of each element of `S` gets bigger.

Comment: I believe linear search will be the fastest. Possibly to make it faster multiple threads can be used after dividing the array (I hope possible in Python). Any other method will rely on processing 'S' to find unique objects or sort which would take up the processing.

Answer (score 0):

Using itertools?

```
from itertools import combinations
for i in combinations(t, len(t)): if i in s: return True;
```

Or using sorted:

```
t = sorted(t)
for i in s: if sorted(i)==t: return True
```

Comment: No sorting is allowed.

Comment: What about itertools? Too slow?

Comment: yes you are checking each permuation against all members of S. So thats K*N, where K is the number of permutations of T.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted`:

```
>>> S = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]]
>>> T = [2,3,1]
>>> any(sorted(T) == sorted(x) for x in S)
True
```

Comment: Sorting is not allowed.

Comment: @user1008636 what do you mean "not allowed"?

Comment: Yes i meant not allowed.

Comment: `sorted` does not sort the original list, if that's your concern. `S` and `T` are still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Collections and counter? It'll run in O(n), whereas sorting will run in roughly O(n log n), and raw comparison will be O(n²)

```
import collections
T = collections.Counter([2,3,1])
any(T == collections.Counter(x) for x in S)
```

Comment: That's stil O(N*K), where N is size of S and K is size of T. If S is big enough it's slow

Answer (score 0):

If a stipulation is without sorting, you might want to look into an order-independent hash function for the combinations. Two starting points I liked were (1) the sum of the hashes of the individual elements of the combination, and (2) a tuple `(sum(combination), product(combination))`.